# Bootstrap step-by-step responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap 3 to make a responsive site, for most of the site the css of bootstrap is fine. For the homepage i have 4 column in a row marked as : col-md-3 that look fine. But when the viewport get smaller and smaller, the column become suddenly 100% wide -> ouch ! that look ugly. What i need to get is to get 4 column, then become 2 column 2 row (50%-50%) then on iphone 100% is fine.... i need incremental responsivness of 25%-25%-25%-25% then 50%-50% then 100%

how is it possible to do that ? if it is !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use col-sm-x for tablets. So in your case col-sm-6 to setup the 2 column 2 rows.

Use col-xs-x for phones. So col-xs-12 to use up the whole width of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Review the "Grid" documentation on the Bootstrap site: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

You need to use a combination of column sizes to change the width based on the screen size.